# How to get Value of another Page in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I dont know how to begin, so i just start with a screenshot and the code of it:

[image: The Textbox.Text-Value should also be in the Textblock at the Bottom here]

---

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="48"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Frame x:Name="MainContent"/>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="Gray">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ResultTB"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="Should also be here"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

---

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainContent.Navigate(typeof(ContentFrame));
    }
```

---

ContentFrame.xaml

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBox x:Name="Input"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             Width="200"/>
</Grid>
```

---

Now i want to grad ResultTB the text of Input. What is the simplest and best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for this in the future - a little similar answer to Alexej but simpler:
For Example, lets say I want to change text of object "SomeObject" (x:Name = "SomeObject") which is in MainPage:

```
MainPage mainFrame = (MainPage)((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Content;
mainFrame.SomeObject = "my text";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use override of Navigate method: [Frame.Navigate(TypeName, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702394.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Where Object is parameter. You can get in another page in OnNavigatedTo event. Something like:

```
string txt=ResultTB.Text;
MainContent.Navigate(typeof(ContentFrame), txt);
```

and on another page add OnNavigatedTo event and inside:

```
var parameter = e.Parameter as string;
```

Comment: Yeah, but i mean when both are already loaded and i change the Text. How can i tell the ResultTB-Textblock on at the other Frame to change his Value to it?

Comment: The best way of doing this is with the MVVM design pattern. You'd create a shared View-Model across both pages which means whenever the string property is updated, it would update the other control also.

Comment: Literally, you can create some global object and bind data to it